# How to manage multiline events based on a random field Logstash

Tags: logstash, multiline, grok

I've been facing a problem related to multiline events lately, and I am needing a little bit of your help for this. My syslog server is sending multi-line events. One single event gathers several lines, and the indicator that proves a particular event line is part of a multi-line event is a random number that defines a user connection session. Here is a custom generated log file:

```
Feb 16 17:29:04 slot1/APM-LTM notice apd[5515]: 01490010:5: 1ec2b273:Username 'cjones'

Feb 16 17:29:04 slot1/APM-LTM warning apd[5515]: 01490106:4: 1ec2b273: AD module: authentication with 'cjones' failed: Preauthentication failed, principal name: cjones@GEEKO.COM. Invalid user credentials. (-1765328360)

Feb 16 17:10:04 slot1/APM-LTM notice apd[5515]: 01490010:5: d8b5a591: Username 'gbridget'

Feb 16 17:10:04 slot1/APM-LTM err apd[5515]: 01490107:3: d8b5a591: AD module: authentication with 'gbridget' failed: Clients credentials have been revoked, principal name: gbridget@GEEKO.COM. User account is locked (-1765328366)

Feb 16 17:29:04 slot1/APM-LTM notice apd[5515]: 01490005:5: 1ec2b273: Following rule 'fallback' from item 'AD Auth' to ending 'Deny'

Feb 16 17:29:04 slot1/APM-LTM notice apd[5515]: 01490102:5: 1ec2b273: Access policy result: Logon_Deny
```

Above are the lines related to two different connections defined by the following user sessions: d8b5a591(user gbridget) and 1ec2b273(user cjones). user sessions are the only indicators that connect those lines to two different events. not to mention that the line events are interwined.

The problem is that I am at loss as to how to explain the above to grok filter with a multiline plugin, knowing that the latter offers too few options. In fact , the notion of "previous" and "next" line cannot be applied here for instance, so the grok options "pattern" and "what" cannot be used, since the events are not necessarily consecutive.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this and tell me if at least it is feasable or not.

Comment: Maybe you could use this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html

Comment: That's actually what I used very long ago :) And it worked fine. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see those as multi-line events, but as related events.  I would load them into elasticsearch as 6 different documents and then query as needed.  If you have specific queries that you're trying to perform against this data, you might ask questions about how to perform them against multiple documents.

One alternative would be to use the session_id as the document ids and then you could update the initial documents when new information came in.  They don't recommend using your own document ids (for performance reasons, IIRC), and updating a document involves deleting the old one and inserting a new one, which is also not good for performance.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to gather the lines related to a particular connection into one single event, hence, one single document, so that I could query one single document to fetch all I need about the related event.

Comment: The events above are loaded as 6 different documents with the current configuration. But what am willing to do is seemingly impossible to query. In fact, I'd like to fetch infos related to one single event; username, client IP etc...for that, one has to query several documents, But so far, I am unable to relate the documents using the session id since it is a random field that cannot be known in advance, and without relating them, elasticsearch is unable to go fetch the right fields. Something like a join has too be done, which ES is seemingly unable to perform.

Comment: It would be something like this: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1785 but rather than dealing with consecutive multiline events, w'd deal with events that come between each others.